# Issue with WSTP

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, python, c++

I'm trying to get [Pythonika](https://github.com/erocarrera/pythonika) to work once again - with the latest version of the WSTP.

The changes required are not many, basically just three:

- Change ML to WS
- Change mprep to wsprep
- Change mcc to wscc

However, I've hitting this error:

```
c++ -I/Users/admin/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Users/admin/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/wstp.framework/Versions/4.25/Headers Pythonika.o Pythonikatm.o -L/Users/admin/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -F/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 -framework Python -F/Users/admin/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -framework wstp -framework CoreFoundation -lWSTPi4  -o Pythonika
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "PyUnicodeString(char
>   const*, unsigned short const*, int)", referenced from:
>         _tr5(WSLink*) in Pythonikatm.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [Pythonika] Error 1

It looks like this is might just be a bug in the template (tm file):

[image]

Because I get an executable compiled after fixing that bug and changing the signature to this:

[image]

However, installing it hangs:

[image]

and I was hoping someone could shed some light on this, or perhaps someone has already upgrading Pythonika to work with 10.3.1 somewhere?

Comment: There's no reason to rewrite everything from `ML` to `WS`.  The `ML` version still ships with Mathematica 10.3.1 and *there's absolutely no difference between the ML and WS versions functionally.*

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I see the support for both, do you know when ML will be deprecated, the documentation says it already is.

Comment: I don't know when they will remove that, but if they do it anytime soon, I'll be very very surprised.  It would render a huge amount of software uncompilable without *a lot* of extra work, so it would be a foolish and senseless move by Wolfram.  Not to mention that `CreateLibrary` (from LibraryLink) still links to the ML version by default.  I haven't tried if it works with the WS version at all!  The LibraryLink headers still use `MLINK`, not `WSLINK`, etc.  If I look inside of the kernel binary, I see all the ML symbols, none of the WS ones. Why would they change them...

Comment: ...internally after all, and risk breaking Mathematica for the sake of a little marketing?  I think that at this point rewriting old programs to use the WS symbols is a waste of time.